# Query calculando datas com INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Salve pessoal,
[Aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cda424/1) tem um exemplo que um cara aqui da comunidade postou
e estou tentando adaptar as minhas necessidades porém surge um error:

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Minha query

```
SELECT
 date_format(TABLE_2.data, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as DATA_2,
 date_format(TABLE_1.data, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as DATA_1, 
 Anos, 
 Mes, 
 Dias,
 Horas,
 Minutos
FROM TABLE_1
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT
 data,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data, TABLE_1.data) as Anos,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,  data, TABLE_1.data) YEAR , TABLE_1.data) AS Mes,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  data, TABLE_1.data) MONTH , TABLE_1.data) AS Dias,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  data, TABLE_1.data) DAY , TABLE_1.data) AS Horas,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,  data, TABLE_1.data) HOUR , TABLE_1.data) AS Minutos
 FROM TABLE_2
)
ON TABLE_2.id = TABLE_1.id
```

Preciso fazer o mesmo que o exemplo só que usando 2 tabelas e com soma de horas e minutos.

Agradeço desde já pela atenção

Comment: Já pesquisou sobre o erro `Every derived table must have its own alias`? Tente colocar um `alias` depois dos parênteses no `INNER JOIN`. Ex.: `tbl2`. E depois no `ON`, faça referência ao `alias` criado. `tbl2.id = TABLE_1.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de um `alias` no `select` interno. De qualquer forma, sua query está errada. `TABLE_1.data` não faz sentido dentro do `select` interno. Tente algo como

```
SELECT
 date_format(TABLE_2.data, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as DATA_2,
 date_format(TABLE_1.data, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as DATA_1, 
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data, TABLE_1.data) as Anos,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,  data, TABLE_1.data) YEAR , TABLE_1.data) AS Mes,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,  data, TABLE_1.data) MONTH , TABLE_1.data) AS Dias,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,  data, TABLE_1.data) DAY , TABLE_1.data) AS Horas,
 TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, data + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,  data, TABLE_1.data) HOUR , TABLE_1.data) AS Minutos
FROM TABLE_1
INNER JOIN TABLE_2
ON TABLE_2.id = TABLE_1.id;
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda irmão. agora surge o erro `#1054 - Unknown column 'TABLE_1.data' in 'field list'`

Comment: TABLE_1 tem a coluna data?

Comment: Sim tem........

Comment: @Hugo o problema é que TABLE_1.data não faz sentido no select interno. não tinha percebido isso.

Comment: E como posso resolver isso @BrunoCalza :(

Comment: @Hugo editei a resposta. forneca mais informações sobre sua estrutura para podermos te ajudar

Comment: agora foi! vlw Brunão

Comment: com essas informações acima daria para pegar o tempo médio geral?